# if/else statement for insert command parameters after select command is implemented c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Access 2003
VS 2010 C#

Please can someone help me how to do a else statement. I have used if statement to check if duplicate record exist and I and struggling on how to use else statement when insert command parameters are used. Thanks in advance

Here is the method for

```
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (var command = myCon.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "select * from SomeTable where ID = @ID";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", int.Parse(txtID.Text));

                myCon.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            txtID.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();

                        }
                    } MessageBox.Show("ID Already exist");
                    else (reader.HasRows !=null // need here pls. 
                    {

                      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, AgeGroup, Gender) VALUES (@ID, @AgeGroup, @Gender)";
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", cBAgeGroup.Text);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cBGender.Text);
                      cmd.Connection = myCon;
                      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                 }

                }
                  //  cmd.Connection = myCon;
                  //  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myCon.Close();
```

**Update 2**
I have moved the cmd connection and cmd.ExecuteNonQuery in the else statement. I am able to check if id already exists and able to insert new record. So the code is executing as it should be.

Thank you all for your advise.

Comment: Please update your title.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @SonerGönül - better?

Comment: Since you tagged with c#, you don't need to write it also..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on, but it seems you have two commands nested. If it were me, I would move the code for INSERT INTO to its own using statement. I would debug it separately to ensure it works. You could use a boolean value so that if your reader had rows, set boolean to true. The do another if statement that checks the boolean and inserts.

Comment: Thanks for reminding Soner

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't even notice the dangling messagebox.

Comment: @SixOThree - I moved the dangling messagebox. I am looking at what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageBox` doesn't belong between the `if` and the `else` and you can use `else` directly:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txtID.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();

    }
} MessageBox.Show("ID Already exist");         // <--- remove this here
else (reader.HasRows !=null // need here pls.  // <--- remove this here
```

So  put the message-box into the `if` where you have detected that there are rows with the given id:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ID Already exist");
    // ...
```

Then you can use insert the new record in the `else` since you already know that the opposite of `HasRows` is "there are no rows":

```
else
{
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, AgeGroup, Gender) VALUES (@ID, @AgeGroup, @Gender)";
  // ...
```

However, i'm not sure if it's the only problem in your code.

**Update** Actually there are other issues, have a look at this completely refactored code:

```
string selectSql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = @ID";
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, AgeGroup, Gender) VALUES (@ID, @AgeGroup, @Gender)";

int id;
if (!int.TryParse(txtID.Text, out id))
    MessageBox.Show("ID must be an integer.");
else
{
    using (var myCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        bool idExistsAlready = true;
        using (var selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectSql, myCon))
        {
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            myCon.Open();
            using (var reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                idExistsAlready = reader.HasRows;
        }
        if (idExistsAlready)
            MessageBox.Show("ID exists already.");
        else
        {
            using (var insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertSql, myCon))
            {
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", cBAgeGroup.Text);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cBGender.Text);
                int affectedRecords = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK Thanks for that. I am receiving error of "Command text was not set for the command object". So I am looking into this. So you are right be suspicious.

Comment: So what does the line of if (!int.TryParse(txtID.Text, out id)) mean?, more specifically out id?

Comment: @bucketblast: [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) converts the string in `txtID.Text` to an `integer`. If it can be parsed it returns `true` and sets the `out`variable. Otherwise it returns `false`. Have a look at msdn for informations on the `out` parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx On this way i precheck if the user entered a valid (integer) ID into the TextBox. If the input is invalid you don't need to touch the database.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Would you disagree the way I did it. My software programming is skills is not my strength? So I don't know